# AHK script to turn hold buttons into toggle buttons

Tags: autohotkey

For instance the Shift button makes things capitals when you have it held down whereas the Capslock button does the same thing but as a toggle.

How can I turn a hold button such as the shift button act like a toggle button like the capslock button?

I have tried this:

```
   if toggle
        Send, {LShift down}
    else
        Send, {LShift up}

LShift::
    toggle := !toggle
    return
```

But it does not work for some reason.
I figure that it will lift up or hold down the LShift button depending on the value of toggle which is changed by the LShift button. But it doesn't work, it's never a capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that popped out to me is that your If Statement is in the Autoexec section of your code and not contained within anything that will be called or executed more than once, so it's only checking Toggle state once, you could hit LShift and change Toggle all day long but no code would happen from there.

First I thought to move your code to the Hotkey section. While this semi worked I wasn't able to produce consistent results, feel free to try yourself:

```
LShift::
    toggle := !toggle 
    if (toggle = true) ; added this for clarity and consitency
        Send, {LShift down}
    else
        Send, {LShift up}
    return
```

Below is a solution I've used in the past, when I remembered it, the reason this works is SetTimer is an interruptible by Hotkeys, so no matter where Timer routine is working the hotkey interrupts it and sets the toggle.

Solution:

```
SetTimer, Toggler, 100 

$LShift::toggle := !toggle

Toggler: 
    if (toggle = true)
        Send, {LShift down}
    else
        Send, {LShift up}
Return
```

Comment: Thanks! could you please also add an explanation as to why what I tried didn't work

Comment: oh okay that makes sense so it only happened once, would it have worked if I had included a while loop around the part at the top? like `while true`?

Comment: It's possible, there are usually multiple solutions to every problem you will face in coding.