# AHK Script to turn toggle buttons into hold buttons

Tags: autohotkey

Similar to my other question: [AHK script to turn hold buttons into toggle buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115326/ahk-script-to-turn-hold-buttons-into-toggle-buttons) but now I'd like to do the opposite.

I want it so as you hold down a key it will trigger an up/down and when you release it will again trigger an up/down.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
LShift down::
    send, {Capslock}

LShift up::
    send, {Capslock}
```

But I'm not sure on the `LShift down::` part I'm pretty sure that won't work, so how can I do something that's effectively the same?

Note: I'm intending to use this for a game so instead of sending Capslock it should ideally send LShift as well, which I think may affect something. But if that's harder then I can just rebind sprint to something other than LShift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle keys are handled differently and use their own commands, read more [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm)

Solution:

```
LShift::
    While (GetKeyState("LShift", "P"))
        SetCapslockState, On   
    SetCapslockState, Off
Return
```

Due to new information, solution #2:

```
LShift::
    While (GetKeyState("LShift", "P"))
        Send, {Capslock Down}  
    Send, {Capslock Up}
Return
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't think this will work as a game wouldn't care about the state of the capslock key but wether it is being pushed down (for hold type) or has been pushed down during the game (for toggle)

Comment: Added code, should work the same but trigger Logical states the "game" will hopefully be reading. Games are tricky and there are all kinds of different input modes you might have to try in order to get anything to work, but that's a whole different topic and wouldn't be possible to discuss it all here.